# Complete the Car class by creating an attribute purchase_price (type int) and the method print_info() that outputs the car's information

Tags: python

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self):
        self.model_year = 0
        # TODO: Declare purchase_price attribute
        self.purchase_price = 0
        self.current_value = 0

    def calc_current_value(self, current_year):
        depreciation_rate = 0.15
        # Car depreciation formula
        car_age = current_year - self.model_year
        self.current_value = round(self.purchase_price * (1 - depreciation_rate) ** car_age)
    
    # TODO: Define print_info() method to output model_year, purchase_price, and current_value


if __name__ == "__main__":    
    year = int(input()) 
    price = int(input())
    current_year = int(input())
    
    my_car = Car()
    my_car.model_year = year
    my_car.purchase_price = price
    my_car.calc_current_value(current_year)
    my_car.print_info()
    
    def print_info(self):

        print("Car's information:")

        print(" Model year:", self.model_year)

        print("Purchase price:", self.purchase_price)
```

good day, I'm supposed to complete the car class, above is my current code, I am not sure how to fix the issue I keep getting the following error: my_car.print_info()
AttributeError: 'Car' object has no attribute 'print_info'

I have tried the above code, and also tried with this

```
def print_info(self):

    print("Car's information:")

    print(" Model year:", self.model_year)

    print("Purchase price:", self.purchase_price)
```

I keep getting the same error.  I am a beginner at this stuff so please help me understand.

Comment: Your `print_info` function has to be part of the class.  That means it needs to be right where that "# TODO" comment is, before your main code.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like your function is outside of the class. notice how you have a #TODO-- this is where you want to insert the function and be mindful of indentations.

Otherwise, your print function is fine.